# How to make sub directories for jobs in Laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am using Laravel 5.1. Generally to generate jobs I do `php artisan make:job SomeJobName`. This would basically create a `SomeJobName` job in the `app/Jobs` directory. But what if my application is huge. I would end up having **a lot** of files in that folder. I want to organize it a little. I want to make sub directories like:

```
app/Jobs/Users/
   Store.php
   Update.php
   Delete.php
app/Jobs/Posts
   Store.php
   Update.php
   Delete.php
```

What is the recommended approach to accomplish this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`artisan make:*` commands will accept a relative namespace so you can do something like this:

```sh
php artisan make:job Users/Store
```

You don't even need to create the sub-directories as artisan will create them if they don't exist.

Comment: Awesome. This one is the best solution. I already knew I could manually fix the namespace etc. and I can manually create or modify the artisan command but I was looking for a solution like this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

That is no problem. Just manually create them and abide to [PSR](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) namespacing rules.

For instance the file `app/Jobs/Posts/Store.php` will hold a class like:

```
namespace App\Jobs\Posts;

use App\Jobs\Job;

class Store extends Job {}
```

You can copy the rest of the class from the auto-generated version or follow [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues#writing-job-classes).

Comment: Thanks but I already knew I could do something like this. I was looking for a solution like nCrazed's. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible if you adjust the namespaces afterwards.

Create the sub directory (eg. Users) , copy your job (eg. Store.php)
and change the namespace to `namespace App\Jobs\Users;`
In the consuming script you must import it with `use App\Jobs\Users\Store;`
or use the full qualifier `\App\Jobs\Users\Store`

Comment: Thanks but I already knew I could do something like this. I was looking for a solution like nCrazed's. Thanks anyway :)